# Angular JS, Add Global Array or Object to Module. Recommended or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When creating an Angular Module one could essentially add global arrays or objects to the module. Like so..

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myModule']);

myApp.run(function()
{

});

angular.module('myModule', [])
.run(function()
{
    // global to module
    var thisModule = angular.module('myModule');
    thisModule.globalArray = [];
    thisModule.globalObject = {};
});
```

So here's the question(s). Would it be a bad idea to do something like this? Is there anything in the documentation that recommends not doing this? And if so, why would or wouldn't you recommend not doing this?

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hrpvkmaj/8/

Comment: personally global declaration shouldn't be there in code..Instead use IIFE pattern.. I'd prefer you should read this http://toddmotto.com/minimal-angular-module-syntax-approach-using-an-iife/

Comment: Kris is not referring to `myApp` being global here, he's referring to the `thisModule.globalObject` part. So IIFE has nothing really to do with it. Presumably he's asking something more along the lines of whether attaching global singletons to the module to simply access everywhere is a good idea (e.g. `thisModule.sessionUser` to access the currently logged in user). Of course I could be wrong. Which is precisely why the Code Review topic is on hold - the question makes a lot more sense with context as to exactly what you want to solve.

Comment: That said, I don't immediately see many cases where this global code shouldn't just go in a Service, or a Provider, or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, Angular goes to great lengths to avoid global state. You can observe this in the dependency injection system that the framework is based on. To use a component, you must inject it as a parameter that is wired up behind the scenes. The framework also has a powerful scoping system that allows for nice and easy encapsulation. Relying on global variables works against these systems.

In particular, it would be a bad idea to do something exactly like your code example because it isn't how Angular was designed to be used. You shouldn't be adding your own properties to Angular's module object. At the very least, you should be injecting the `$rootScope` object and adding your global variables to that.

```
app.run(function($rootScope)
{
    $rootScope.globalArray = [];
    $rootScope.globalObject = {};
});
```

From the Angular documentation:

> Every application has a single root scope. All other scopes are descendant scopes of the root scope.

If you went this route, you could inject `$rootScope` wherever you need to use those global values.

[However, the Angular team discourages using `$rootScope`.](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.

There is another way of defining global values in Angular that is even preferable over using `$rootScope`: defining a `value` provider.

A value provider is the simplest kind of provider. It defines a single value that can be injected throughout your app.

You can define one like this:

```
app.value("myValue", {
    someProp: 'Hello World'
});
```

Then you can inject the value wherever you need it like this:

```
app.controller("myController", function ($scope, myValue) {
    $scope.someValue = myValue.someProp;
});
```

[Here's a fiddle using a value provider to inject a global value.](http://jsfiddle.net/7g1r3mv1/)

In the end, any answer you get, including this one, will include some level of subjectivity. There are many ways to handle global values, but Angular provides some really convenient ways of using the framework to accomplish this.

Comment: thanks for the response. So is injecting into the `$rootScope` a common practice. If you where to use a third party module for example. Would you cringe if that module was injecting into the `$rootScope`?

Comment: It's hard to say how common it is, but its there to be used. If you determine $rootScope is the best solution, go with it. how a 3rd party module uses its `$rootScope` doesn't concern me as long as the module does its job. The recommendation against `$rootScope` has to do with the testability and maintainability of your project.

Comment: Okay, and just so I am clear `rootScope` is shared between all modules. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `$rootScope` is an ancestor for all scopes in an app (ng-app).